# Is there a single word for not in expected time?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

For example, I expect something to be delivered in a specific time range, but it can be delivered before or after the time range. What would be the best single word to describe '**before or after expected time**' in English ?

Comment: *anytime*? There is no boundary since it can be delivered anytime before the expected time and anytime after it.

Comment: Hmm, but I want to exclude the specified time range, `anytime` includes my time range also

Comment: Like *not between noon and three?*

Comment: @Davo yes like `not between noon and three`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also say *outside* the hours of noon and three.

This link to the definition of [office hours](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/office-hours) uses the exact definition you are looking for in its example:

> the hours during the day when people who work in offices are usually at work:
>   *I'll have to do it outside/out of (= before or after) office hours.*

Answer (score 1):

You could define the acceptable times:

> The delivery should occur tomorrow, **before noon or after three.**

Or you could define the unacceptable time:

> The delivery should occur tomorrow, **but not between noon and three.**

Or:

> We can accept delivery any time **[except](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/except) between noon and three.**

---

Definition of **except** from [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/except):

> with the exclusion or exception of